# Twig Compare a parameter passed to a template inside the template

Tags: symfony, twig

In Twig I successfully render a template and pass to it the following array with values:

```
    $params = array(
                    'value1'    => 'y',
                    'value2'    => 'x'
                );
```

Inside the template I render, I want to  have an if-statement in which to compare the value of 'value1' to a string variable.

Something like

```
    {% set type =  {{ value1 }}  %}
    {%  if type == y %}
       {* do code *}
    {%  elseif type == b %}
       {* do code *}
```

How can I assign the value of {{ value1 }} to type, as this example does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `{% set type =  value1  %}`

But why not just:

```
{% if value1 == y  %}

{% elseif value2 == x %}

{% endif %}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

```
{% set type = params['value1']   %}
```

Or more simply:

```
{% set type = params.value1   %}
```

More info [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) in the doc

Then you can use in the if statements as usually:

```
{%  if type == 'x' %}
      do something for the X case 
{%  elseif type == 'y' %}
      do somethingelse for the Y case
{% endif %}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/zshou9) a working example.

Hope this help

Comment: If OP passes the array like : `$twig->render('template.html, $parms');` then this is incorrect as it would just be `{% set type = value1 %}`

Comment: `{% set type = params['value1']   %}` and `{% set type = params.value1   %}` do not work, it turns out value1 can be referred just by its name. So  `{% set type =  value1  %}` works just fine. Eventually, I used only `{% if value1 == y  %}

{% elseif value2 == x %}

{% endif %}`